# How to take backup of whole application in android?

Tags: android

I want to store/save the whole application, that is to create a backup so that whenever required, will be able to restore the same previous state of application.
Can it be done with backup manager or any other way.

Comment: Its restored your application when you have a proper back up your data. So whenever any update or reinstalling the app. Your data automatically restored. Hope you will understand it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can backup the user data, so in essence the application *state* to a cloud. The apk is just a glorified zip file, it makes not sense backing that up.

There is an [entire article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html) dedicated to this.

Comment: i have done a sample program with the help of backup manager, a file is created in package folder which saves some data the path is, data\data\com.abc\files\savedfile but when i uninstall the application this file is deleted and hence the whole stored data is lost.
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/index.html
this is the link from where i got the sample am i heading the right way..as i have to backup the whole application not only some data.

Comment: Uninstalling and reinstalling should restore your file, *provided that* you've backed it up first. Look at [this code](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/src/com/example/android/backuprestore/FileHelperExampleAgent.html), it backs up a file.

Answer (score 3):

**Android's backup service** allows you to copy your persistent application data to remote "cloud" storage, in order to provide a restore point for the application data and settings. If a user performs a factory reset or converts to a new Android-powered device, the system automatically restores your backup data when the application is re-installed. This way, your users don't need to reproduce their previous data or application settings. This process is completely transparent to the user and does not affect the functionality or user experience in your application.

Look at this [Data Backup](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html).

Comment: i have done a sample program with the help of backup manager, a file is created in package folder which saves some data the path is, data\data\com.abc\files\savedfile but when i uninstall the application this file is deleted and hence the whole stored data is lost.
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/BackupRestore/index.html
this is the link from where i got the sample am i heading the right way..as i have to backup the whole application not only some data.

Answer (score 1):

Please Go through Data Backup
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html